# Can't get toFixed() to work

Tags: jquery

I'm having jQuery do some calculations for me when user inputs into a field.

When I set it up, I still get results that can have greater than 4 decimal places.

**jQuery function**

```
$(function() {
    var labor = $('#labor');
    var cost = $('#cost');
    var RPH = $('#rph');

    labor.keyup(function() {
        parseFloat(RPH.val( labor.val() / cost.val() ) ).toFixed(2);
    });

    cost.keyup(function() {
        parseFloat(RPH.val( labor.val() / cost.val() ) ).toFixed(2);
    });
});
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Point of note: JavaScript is doing the calculations, not jQuery.

Comment: It looks like you're using `parseFloat` and `toFixed` correctly, but once those functions run, you aren't doing anything with the result. Did you mean to replace the value of `labor` or `cost` with the result?

Comment: toFixed is working fine, you're just not doing anything with the value it returns.

Comment: Makes since. RPH is what I want my return value to be. Would I need to set it up differently to get however many decimal places need to be displayed?

Comment: But you're setting the value of RPH before you're calling toFixed and parseFloat, so those functions are never applied to your value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually set the value to `toFixed`'s result, and you need to use `parseFloat` on the values before you do calculations on them.

```
RPH.val((parseFloat(labor.val()) / parseFloat(cost.val())).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you all for your input. I see how to properly use this function now.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter in this example since you're using the result in the DOM, but worth noting that you'd need another .parseFloat() if you wanted the end result to be a number - .toFixed() returns a string.

Comment: @Ben true, but then you would lose any trailing zeros. So I think he's after getting a string here.

Comment: I'll have to check and see if the final RPH value will have any issue when posting it into my sql server database. If it does, I'll do what @Ben suggested and it should be fine.